# multiline string input from stdin in c

Tags: c, stdin, eof

I try in my C program multiline input form stdin with newline with this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

#define DEFAULT_INPUT_LENGTH 20

char * readMessage(FILE* file);
void writeChar(char* string, char c);


int main()
{
    printf("Message:\n");
    char * msg = readMessage(stdin);

    printf("Input: %s\n", msg);


    free(msg);


    return 0;
};

char * readMessage(FILE* file)
{
    char *input = malloc(DEFAULT_INPUT_LENGTH);

    int inputCounter = 0;
    int n = 1;
    char c;

    while(!feof(stdin))
    {
        c=fgetc(file);

        inputCounter++;

        if (inputCounter == DEFAULT_INPUT_LENGTH * n)
        {
            n++;
            int chars = DEFAULT_INPUT_LENGTH * n;

            input = realloc(input, chars);
        }

        writeChar(input, c);
    }

    return input;
}




void writeChar(char* in, char c)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        if (in[i] == '\0')
        {
            in[i] = c;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

But when i try CTRL+D on Linux or CTRL+Z in Windows the input isnt ended.

Example of input something like this:

```
asfer
dfdfd
sffdfl
```

in this example if i try CTRl+D after the last l char the input isnt ended i must use enter and the CTRL+D

after newline in last line hint CTRL+Z and ENTER and
[image]

Comment: 1) Need `*input = 0;`  at first. 2) `char c;` --> `int c;` 3) `while(!feof(stdin))
    {
        c=fgetc(file);` --> `while((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF){` 4) `in[i] = c;` --> `in[i] = c; in[i+1] = 0;`

Comment: i try this changes in windows but still CTRL+Z after last char not ended input

Comment: type only CTRL+Z with enter in a line. Do not enter(CTRL+Z) following characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEFAULT_INPUT_LENGTH 20

char * readMessage(FILE* file);
void writeChar(char* string, char c);

int main(void){
    printf("Message:\n");
    char * msg = readMessage(stdin);

    printf("Input: %s\n", msg);

    free(msg);

    return 0;
}

char * readMessage(FILE* file){
    char *input = malloc(DEFAULT_INPUT_LENGTH);

    int inputCounter = 0;
    int n = 1;
    int c;//!

    *input = 0;//!

    while((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF){//!
        inputCounter++;

        if (inputCounter == DEFAULT_INPUT_LENGTH * n){
            n++;
            int chars = DEFAULT_INPUT_LENGTH * n;

            input = realloc(input, chars);
        }

        writeChar(input, c);
    }

    return input;
}

void writeChar(char* in, char c){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; ; i++){
        if (in[i] == '\0'){
            in[i] = c;
            in[i+1] = 0;//!
            break;
        }
    }

}
```